# marge embedded JSON objects with powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have following *ConvertFrom-Json* output from JSON file:

```
Id                 : 1
ItemName           : TestFile
SharingInformation : {@{RecipientEmail=complianceadmin@dev.onmicrosoft.com; ResharePermission=Read}, @{RecipientEmail=test@dev.onmicrosoft.com; ResharePermission=Read}}
```

I would like to save this data to .csv file in following manner as columns:

```
Id                 : 1
ItemName           : TestFile
Users              : (read) test@dev.domain.com ; (write) test2@dev.domain.com
```

as columns.. Here you can find part of my actual PS code (which do not work properly when there is more than one embedded values):

```
$JSONFile = $ExctratedFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$psObjectForCsv = $JSONFile | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "id"=$_.Id
        "ItemName"=$_.ItemName
        "RecipientEmail"=$_.SharingInformation.RecipientEmail
        "ResharePermission"=$_.SharingInformation.ResharePermission

    }
}
$psObjectForCsv | Export-Csv -path $fileName -Force -NoTypeInformation
}
```

do you have any ideas how to achieve this?

Thank you for your help!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the SharingInformation in any form you like.

Try

```
$JSONFile = $ExctratedFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$result   = $JSONFile | ForEach-Object {
    # output a formatted string "(permission) emailaddress" 
    $users = foreach ($shareInfo in $_.SharingInformation) {
        '({0}) {1}' -f $shareInfo.ResharePermission, $shareInfo.RecipientEmail
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id       = $_.Id
        ItemName = $_.ItemName
        Users    = $users -join "; "
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path $fileName -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: that's working:) is there any way to sort values by $shareInfo.ResharePermission ?

Comment: @anders1990 You could do `$users = foreach ($shareInfo in ($_.SharingInformation | Sort-Object ResharePermission)) {
        '({0}) {1}' -f $shareInfo.ResharePermission, $shareInfo.RecipientEmail
    }`.